# Weird bug in 'tar' not including files named .__init__.py

Tags: mac, tar

Does anyone know why `tar` is not including files named `.__init__.py` (note the dot)?

```
$ mkdir /tmp/work && cd /tmp/work
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/.__init__.py
$ touch foo/.namespace__init__.py
$ tar czf foo.tar.gz foo

$ mkdir e && mv foo.tar.gz e/ && cd e/
$ tar zxf foo.tar.gz
$ ls -al foo/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 sridharr  wheel  102 14 Mar 17:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 sridharr  wheel  136 14 Mar 17:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 sridharr  wheel    0 14 Mar 17:16 .namespace__init__.py
$ 

$ echo ".__init__.py file is missing. WTF? This is OSX 10.6"
```

**Update**: tar appears to be ignoring files starting with `._` characters; why?

**Update 2**: I cannot reproduce this on Linux.

Comment: Odd that the tar function on mac can't make this distinction.

Comment: Ironically, there is a [question](http://superuser.com/questions/259703/get-mac-tar-to-stop-putting-filenames-in-tar-archives) asking how to make `tar` _exclude_ `._` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. On Apple systems, files starting with `._` contains [resource fork](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20578) of another file. They are not normal files that can be copied and moved around.

Comment: This is correct; ._ is special on Mac OS. http://arstechnica.com/reviews/os/macosx-10.4.ars/7 Upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

There are some undocumented(?) environment variables that can be used to disable the special handling of extended attributes and/or resource forks in *tar* (and *pax*, for what it is worth). *rsync* has the `-E`/`--extended-attributes` option to enable(**!**) this handling—but on some non-Apple *rsync*﻿s `-E` means `--executability` instead.

On Mac OS X 10.4 (the first release that created these AppleDouble-encoded `._*` archive members), the environment variable is `COPY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_DISABLE`. In Leopard and Snow Leopard, the variable is `COPYFILE_DISABLE`. Typically the variables just have to be set. Any value will do (even the empty string), but `true` seems to be traditional. Thus:

```
COPY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_DISABLE=true COPYFILE_DISABLE=true tar …
```

Setting this variable has the following effects:

- When creating/updating archives:

  - Prevents the creation of `._*` archive members when archiving files with extended attributes.
  - Allows the creation of `._*` archive members when archiving actual `._*` files.
- When extracting archives:

  - Causes `._*` archive members to be extracted as plain files instead of restoring the extended attributes to the related file.

**In short, setting these variables makes *tar*, et al. act like they would on (e.g.) Linux.**

If you rarely need to archive files that have extended attributes or resource forks, and you might need to archive or extract actual `._*` files, then you might consider setting and exporting these variables in one of your shell initialization files:

```
# Tell tar, pax, etc. on Mac OS X 10.4+ not to archive
# extended attributes (e.g. resource forks) to ._* archive members.
# Also allows archiving and extracting actual ._* files.
COPY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_DISABLE=true COPYFILE_DISABLE=true
export COPY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_DISABLE COPYFILE_DISABLE
```

---

These `._*` files are also used to store extended attributes on filesystems that do not support them—most commonly the FAT variants. These variables will not really help when dealing with `._*` files on other filesystems, just archives.

The HFS+ filesystem used in Mac OS X is perfectly capable of storing actual `._*` files, so once you use the variables to extract the files to the filesystem, the files can be accessed properly in all the normal ways.

Comment: https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/commit/7cf625f3e1ff2f376d265465f8f97dd5b8953ef2#commitcomment-9636090 and http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=20684196#post20684196 draw attention to the outdated documentation from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate this on a Debian 5.0 host.  Perhaps there is a bug in the version of tar installed on the system you are using?  What version of *nix are you using?

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/.namespace__init__.py
$ touch foo/.__init__.py
$ tar -czvf foo.tar.gz foo/
foo/
foo/.namespace__init__.py
foo/.__init__.py

$ # example the file
$ tar -tzvf foo.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x cfrancy/cfrancy   0 2010-03-14 17:34 foo/
-rw-r--r-- cfrancy/cfrancy   0 2010-03-14 17:34 foo/.namespace__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- cfrancy/cfrancy   0 2010-03-14 17:34 foo/.__init__.py
```