# The files after extracting a tar

Tags: windows, macos, tar, file-archiver

I recently start to use tar to backup my files on macOS.

I usually use:

```
tar cvf archive.tar foo bar
```

and i also run this to check:

```
tar tvf archive.tar
```

It would show the following and it seems okay:

```
-rw-r--r--  0       6 Jan 20 22:40 foo
-rw-r--r--  0      13 Jan 20 22:40 bar
```

However, It seems likes this on Windows.

```
-rw-r--r--  0       6 Jan 20 22:40 ._foo
-rw-r--r--  0       6 Jan 20 22:40 foo
-rw-r--r--  0      13 Jan 20 22:40 ._bar
-rw-r--r--  0      13 Jan 20 22:40 bar
```

I'm confused about the result.

Why it would output ._foo and ._bar? Where are they from?

How could i make an archive.tar only output foo and bar without ._foo and ._bar?

Comment: You're probably seeing the resource forks/extended attributes, that Windows doesn't know what to do with. The Mac would wrap them back into the file. See https://superuser.com/questions/119928/weird-bug-in-tar-not-including-files-named-init-py and https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder

Comment: @Tetsujin
Thank you for your comment! It really help me a lot:)

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski
Thank you for advice, i answer my own question, and i don't need futher help.

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed about extended attributes, and i export the following variable:

```
export COPY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_DISABLE=true
export COPYFILE_DISABLE=true
```

Now it wouldn't output ._file on windows.

Comment: You may accept your own answer two days later.